# TAggregateField not calculated when Index of ClientDataset changes

Tags: delphi, indexing, aggregate, tclientdataset

I am using a TClientDataset, connected to a DBGrid, with a couple of Aggregate Fields, for calculating the SUM of an other couple of Float Fields. All fields have been created in Design time.

Everything is working as expected, until the time that the IndexName of the ClientDataset changes with a custom Index, in order to sort the Grid. After that, the Aggregate Fields don't calculate their value properly, and they are set with Null value.

The problem occurs in Delphi XE7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have google about it and i found a solution that worked for me [here](http://forums.devart.com/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=27750)

There is a bug at **TCustomClientDataSet.SetIndex** method that is declared in the **DBClient** unit.
The solution propose to replace the following code

```
if FAggregatesActive then
begin
    FAggFieldsInit := False;
    ResetAllAggs(FAggregatesActive);
```

with the next one

```
if FAggregatesActive then
begin
    CloseAggs;
    ResetAllAggs(FAggregatesActive);
```

As far as i understand, the replacement of *FAggFieldsInit := False* with *CloseAggs*, force the Aggregates to be released and then recalculate with the new index.
As i said this solution worked for me, and i haven't notice any unwanted behavior.

*The credit goes to AndreyZ for the original solution.*